# ProgressBar и Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

В **Memo** расположено три строки:

```
11
22
33
```

По нажатию на кнопку удаляю первую строку Memo:

```
Memo1.Lines.delete(0);
```

Как сделать что бы **ProgressBar** заполнялся по мере удаления строк из **Memo** (То есть удалена первая строка **ProgressBar** изменился, вторая, третья...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При самом первом нажатии установите предел прогресса

```
if FirstFlag then begin
   ProgressBar.Max := Memo1.Lines.Count;
   ProgressBar.Position := 1;
   FirstFlag := False;
end
```

При последующих выполняется

```
else
    ProgressBar.Position := ProgressBar.Position + 1;
```

А где `FirstFlag` задать - это уж сами смотрите, какая должна быть логика

Comment: Спасибо Вам MBo только прочитала ваш ответ.